# Perform Conditional Grouping and selecting second best row using Cumcount in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

Here is the data that I have:

```
ID              Vehicle     Calculator     Offer NextCalculator NextOffer
3497827 2002 Ford Explorer Manheim Salvage 190  Copart           190
3497827 2002 Ford Explorer Manheim Salvage 190  IAA              140
3497827 2002 Ford Explorer Manheim Salvage 190  Manheim Salvage  190
3497827 2002 Ford Explorer Manheim Salvage 190  SVP              55
3497828 2003 Honda CRV     Manheim Salvage 320  Copart           150
3497828 2003 Honda CRV     Manheim Salvage 320  IAA              320
3497828 2003 Honda CRV     Manheim Salvage 320  Manheim Salvage  320
3497828 2003 Honda CRV     Manheim Salvage 320  SVP              200
```

What I want to do is find out which is the next best calculator offer for each vehicle? E.g. for 3497827, next best offer is Copart - 190 (not considering Manheim Salvage since we want the next after it) and for 3497828 next best offer would be IAA - 320.

So far I have done

```
df = df.sort_values(['ID', 'NextOffer'], ascending=False)
df1 = df[df.groupby('ID').cumcount() == 1]
```

which gives me:

```
ID              Vehicle     Calculator     Offer NextCalculator NextOffer
3497827 2002 Ford Explorer Manheim Salvage 190  Manheim Salvage           190
3497828 2003 Honda CRV     Manheim Salvage 320  IAA              320
```

It gives me correct result only if the `NextOffers` are lesser than the Offer value, but not if `NextOffer` is same as Offer.

What I want is:

```
ID              Vehicle     Calculator     Offer NextCalculator NextOffer
3497827 2002 Ford Explorer Manheim Salvage 190  Copart           190
3497828 2003 Honda CRV     Manheim Salvage 320  IAA              320
```

So my guess is that first I would have to do cumcount() == 0 and if for that row `NextCalculator` is same as `Calculator` then I would have to get the second row using cumcount() == 1. Any help in how can I do this or is there any efficient way to get the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [21]: df.loc[df.query("Calculator != NextCalculator")
                  .groupby('ID', as_index=False).NextOffer.idxmax()]
Out[21]:
             ID        Vehicle       Calculator  Offer NextCalculator  NextOffer
0  3497827 2002  Ford Explorer  Manheim Salvage    190         Copart        190
5  3497828 2003      Honda CRV  Manheim Salvage    320            IAA        320
```